# Updating app with different key

Tags: android, apk, signed, android-keystore

I updated Android Studio yesterday and today I wasn't able to update my app on Google Play Store. When I upload the APK file, Google tells me that the app is signed with a different key but I used the same keystore as always, how can I fix this? How can I check which keys are stored in my keystore and how to choose which one to use?
I saw other similar questions but it was not enough detailed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use something like this if you are not good with the command line http://www.keystore-explorer.org/

Comment: Oh thanks, thanks to you I was able to copy my keys between to keystores and solve the problem , please answer the question introducing this awesome software !

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the APK that is currently online, you can check the signed certificate hashes.

Firstly get the hashes of your APK that is online:

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile online.apk
```

Then check the hash of your newer APK:

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile new.apk
```

You can compare for example, the SHA1 hash:

`SHA1: 00:...*snip*...:FF`

If they don't match then you know that the keystore you are using is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio when you **Generate Signed APK**, and select the correct key store. Once you enter the correct keystore password, you will be able to select stored keys in **Key alias** part. Click on **...** and in new dialog (**Choose Key**) you will see all your stored keys under **Use an existing key** dropdown